# Forin loop in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

In objective-c `for-in` loop control flow can be written by

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = //some values and keys
for(id key in [dictionary allKeys])
```

What is the syntax for this (or alternative for `for-in`) control flow in swift?

Comment: Please read the documentation. This will take about 2 minutes to find.

Answer (score 3):

If you use tuples you have more control:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    println("key is \(key)")
    println("value is \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
var dictionary = //some values and keys
for(key in dictionary.allKeys())
{
}
```